# Adding memory allocation and memset after a prior call to string::find causes it to return npos. Why?

Tags: c++, x86-64

I'm reverse engineering a game called Monster Hunter World to add a better mouse handling subroutine and I'm having a very bizarre bug pop up in my software. I don't know precisely whats causing it but I can explain some symptoms and I strongly suspect memory corruption.

The problem occurs when I use `string::find` on a string containing the whole binary file of MonsterHunterWorld.exe to find a byte pattern for a protection mechanism that checksums the file and intentionally crashes the program if any modifications are detected. Up until a recent change to my code my software was able to successfully find these byte patterns, the following changes to my code result in the `string::find` function failing:

```
char buffer2[5000];
memset(buffer2, 0, sizeof(buffer2));
```

This is after the find function has been called. If I remove this from the program it works as expected (the call to string::find properly finds the byte pattern I search for).

For reference the entire source code for the program can be found in this paste bin-
https://pastebin.com/7ExgmXNZ

Something else I checked out is I decided to open the software in x64dbg, I found that the pattern I search for with string::find is in fact in the string it is searching, but for some reason it fails anyway.

The source code was compiled with 64 bit MingW version 8.1.0

EDIT: changed pastebin to Minimal code required to reproduce the problem

UPDATE: I was able to solve the problem for my specific program but I am unsatisfied as I don't fully understand why the solution works. To the end of the char array that I supply as the `str` parameter to `string::find` I manually add a null terminating `0x00`. AFAIK char arrays initialized like so:

```
char foo[] = {0x68, 0x69}; //"hi"
```

are supposed to have null terminators added to them automatically? If this is untrue someone PLEASE correct me because that's a pretty serious error on my part and that would mean the only reason the program was working before was by dumb luck that the memory adjacent to my char array happened to be 0x00.

Comment: You shouldn't store binary data in a `std::string`. It's likely to contain many zero elements that may make the string appear much shorter than it is.

Comment: std::string fully supports binary data, the confusion is only if you then try to use the data as a c-string.

Comment: Please extract a [mcve]. That said, using a vector instead of a string to contain raw bytes would be better, though a string could work (to a limited extent), too.

Comment: If you now have a [mcve], it should be small enough to include directly into the question, as required by SO rules.  [ask].  A link to your complete project can sometimes be useful for people that want to see the context, but the MCVE must be in the question, not just linked to.

Comment: @Peter Perhaps I missed it but I don't see anywhere in your links that specify the code must be small enough to include directly into the question itself to qualify as Minimal, complete and verifiable. Could you point out the excerpt that explicitly states that?

Comment: The *Help others reproduce the problem* section of [ask] says your code *must* be in your question, not just linked to.  And it reminds you that you need to boil it down to a *minimal* example, including the input that makes it fail.  Given that SO questions and answers have a 30k char limit, if your code doesn't fit in the question then it's too large for any reasonable person to consider it minimal.  Even in a programming language like BF or Brain-Flack (https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brain-Flak where it takes a huge amount of characters to do some simple things), 30k chars is *huge*.

Comment: @PeterCordes It does not explicitly state that my code must be in my question, the closest thing to the statement you are making is: "If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - but also include the code in your question itself" for one this is said to be a guideline, not an absolute rule like you make it out to be. Second the dependency for this guideline is that I'm linking to a _live_ example, which pastebin is not.

Comment: The wording in [ask] isn't explicit enough.  In https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") **must include** the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary** to reproduce it **in the question itself**.*  Lacking a [mcve] in the question is one of the close-vote reasons that pops up in the menu when you click "close" under a question.  See also http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/.

Comment: You are/were completely missing the point of the wording you quoted.  It's saying that *even* runnable off-site links aren't sufficient.  Posting a pastebin link (which is less helpful than a link to the code where you could run it online) doesn't exempt you from the requirement that questions be self-contained.

Comment: @PeterCordes That's your opinion, not fact. I don't prefer to argue and the meta is more of a place for it anyway. I really think you should stop going around making false claims about question requirements though.

Comment: I'd say that whether his claim holds follows from the rationale. Since SO is intended as a QA knowledge base, it requires that the knowledge is contained here. A pastebin link has an expiry time. Any external link is always subject to change. Therefore, it is usually considered not suitable to satisfy the requirement that Peter mentioned. I personally support that interpretation. However, you're free to do research and discussion concerning that on meta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the reason this is happening is because  [`string::find(const CharT* str, size_type pos = 0 );`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) expects a null terminator for the `str` parameter and I thought that my char array would be given one automatically.

This is not the case and the reason it was working before was completely due to luck that the adjacent memory was 0x00, and now that I changed the code the adjacent memory was changed to 0x40 and resulted in string::find searching for the wrong string.